# combine multiple set functions into one generic setter in java

Tags: java, reflection

I have the a class with the following public methods:

```
    public void setStartGameEvent(GameTypeMode gameTypeMode) {
        gameTypeMode.setGameType(readIntFromConsole());
    }

    @Override
    public void setComputerHeuristicEvent(GameTypeMode gameTypeMode) {
        gameTypeMode.setComputerHeuristic(readIntFromConsole());
    }

    @Override
    public void setBackgroundChoice(GameTypeMode gameTypeMode) {
        gameTypeMode.setBackground(readIntFromConsole());
    }


    @Override
    public void setBorderChoice(GameTypeMode gameTypeMode) {
        gameTypeMode.setBorder(readIntFromConsole());
    }
```

notes:

- the class is a proxy, that's why the input of the function is where we want to set the data - the class is a consoleEventHandler, the main class does eventHandler.setBlah(GameTypeMode) and gets the data from the correct input method.
- readIntFromConsole() is just reading an int from standart input and handels exceptions.

as you can easily see all the function are doing exactly the same, just with different set attributes.
my question is if there's a way to do it in a more generic\sophisticated way such as reflection or anything similar

edit: more explanations about this class

this class is a part of a game.
the input of the game can be from console\graphic display\ mouse etc.
the output (the game itself) is created accordingly to the input method that was chosen.

I have an eventHandler interface which define all the function that a specific input method should implement so the game would work (such as the functions above)
this means that I have consoleEventHandler, graphicEventHandler ...

now for each attribute I need to implement a set method for all eventHandler availabe (which might be a lot), that's why i'm asking this question about generalizing the set function for each eventHandler

Comment: Using reflection to solve this "problem" is like using a nuclear bomb to avoid changing the batteries in your remote. If it really bothers you, you could take a look at what Java does for the Calendar class, although again you're probably asking for more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Why does this class exist just to pass calls along to another class? It's even getting the class to call passed into it! The entire block of code is entirely redundant...so no wonder it seems redundant :s

Comment: If you explain what possible reason there is for this class to exist we may be able to give you a less crazy way to do it :D

Answer (score 0):

Anything you come up with will be more complicated than the obvious, straight-forward code shown.

At this level of abstraction, with this trivial amount of "duplication", the cost *far* outweighs any benefits.

Comment: even when for every attribute i'll add in the future i'll have to create another setFunction (actually a few functions because of the eventHandler interface -> all sub classes) ? tnx

Comment: @ShaiZarzewski Almost certainly yes. It's further complicated because not every method is named the same way, so you'll have an arbitrary number of things to check *anyway*. Java doesn't have a "method missing" function. If you want this type of abstraction, Java isn't the best choice. You *might* want to look into some of the Apache Commons BeanUtils and/or PropertyUtils&ndash;they have a number of ways to define the shuttling of information from one instance to another.